# Как показать содержимое за overflow scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужно как-то показать содержимое за проделами overflow.

```css
$blue: #0084ff;
$blue-darker: darken($blue, 5);

body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.backpack {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #000;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  
  &__container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 85px);
    gap: 10px;
  }
  
  &__item {
    width: 90px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    cursor: pointer;
    
    &:hover > .backpack__itemDescription {
      display: block;
    }
  }
  
  &__itemDescription {
    display: none;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="backpack">
  <div class='backpack__container'>
   <div class='backpack__item'>
    <div class='backpack__itemName'>
      item_name
    </div>
    <div class='backpack__itemDescription'>
       item_hover
     </div>
   </div>
   
   <div class='backpack__item'>
    <div class='backpack__itemName'>
      item_name
    </div>
    <div class='backpack__itemDescription'>
       item_hover
     </div>
   </div>
   
    <div class='backpack__item'>
     <div class='backpack__itemName'>
      item_name
     </div>
     <div class='backpack__itemDescription'>
       item_hover
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Может есть другие способы это сделать?
**Ссылка на пример:**
http://jsfiddle.net/3qnjst19/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно делать Описание (Description), в виде полноценной всплывающей подсказки или модального окна или, вовсе, отдельной страницей. Но, раз такая задумка, и хочется "по-лёгкому", то могу предложить два варианта (недостатков много, но такова цена простоты):

---

#### JS, CSS и "недоподсказка"

- Создаём дополнительный `<div>` и используем его в качестве слоя-контейнера для показа описаний.
- При наведении на какой-либо `.backpack__item`, находим в нём `.backpack__itemDescription` и клонируем найденное в "слой-подсказку", не забывая при этом  правильно позиционировать.
- После ухода курсора из блока, удаляем клонированное содержимое.

```js
const oB = document.querySelector(".backpack");
const oBC = document.querySelector(".backpack__container");
const oBIDL = document.querySelector(".backpack__itemDescription-layer");
oBC.addEventListener("mouseover", function(ev) {
  let oT = ev.target;
  if ((oP = oT.closest(".backpack__item"))) {
    let oCD = oBIDL.appendChild(
      oP.querySelector(".backpack__itemDescription").cloneNode(true)
    );
    oBIDL.style.left = `${oP.offsetLeft}px`;
    oBIDL.style.top = `${oP.offsetTop - oB.scrollTop}px`;
  }
});
oBC.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
  oBIDL.innerHTML = "";
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262e;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.backpack {
  width: 300px; height: 300px;
  background-color: #000;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.backpack__container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 85px);
  gap: 10px;
}

.backpack__item {
  width: 90px; height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.backpack__itemDescription {
  display: none;
  width: 150px; height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 1000;
}
.backpack__itemDescription-layer .backpack__itemDescription {
  display: block;
}
.backpack__itemDescription-layer {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="backpack">
  <div class='backpack__container'>
    <div class='backpack__item'>
      <div class='backpack__itemName'>item_name</div>
      <div class='backpack__itemDescription'>item_hover</div>
    </div>
    <div class='backpack__item'>
      <div class='backpack__itemName'>item_name</div>
      <div class='backpack__itemDescription'>item_hover</div>
    </div>
    <div class='backpack__item'>
      <div class='backpack__itemName'>item_name</div>
      <div class='backpack__itemDescription'>item_hover</div>
    </div>
    <div class='backpack__item'>
      <div class='backpack__itemName'>item_name</div>
      <div class='backpack__itemDescription'>item_hover</div>
    </div>
    <div class='backpack__item'>
      <div class='backpack__itemName'>item_name</div>
      <div class='backpack__itemDescription'>item_hover</div>
    </div>
    <div class='backpack__item'>
      <div class='backpack__itemName'>item_name</div>
      <div class='backpack__itemDescription'>item_hover</div>
    </div>
    <div class='backpack__item'>
      <div class='backpack__itemName'>item_name</div>
      <div class='backpack__itemDescription'>item_hover</div>
    </div>
    <div class='backpack__item'>
      <div class='backpack__itemName'>item_name</div>
      <div class='backpack__itemDescription'>item_hover</div>
    </div>
    <div class='backpack__item'>
      <div class='backpack__itemName'>item_name</div>
      <div class='backpack__itemDescription'>item_hover</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='backpack__itemDescription-layer'></div>
```

Основной минус данного подхода - проблемы позиционирования (и поведение в целом) при прокрутке блока.

---

#### CSS и выравнивание

На мой взгляд, более изящно это можно решить, если не давать описаниям выходить за границы блока.

- Здесь просто задаём выравнивание (влево-центр-вправо), в зависимости от расположения блоков.

```css
body {
  background: #20262e;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.backpack {
  width: 300px; height: 300px;
  background-color: #000;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.backpack__container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 85px);
  gap: 10px;
}

.backpack__item {
  width: 90px; height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.backpack__itemDescription {
  display: none;
  width: 150px; height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  top: 0; z-index: 1000;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.backpack__item:hover>.backpack__itemDescription {
  display: block;
}
.backpack__item:nth-child(3n-2) .backpack__itemDescription {
  left: 0;
}
.backpack__item:nth-child(3n-1) .backpack__itemDescription {
  left: 50%; transform: translatex(-50%);
}
.backpack__item:nth-child(3n) .backpack__itemDescription {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="backpack">
  <div class='backpack__container'>
    <div class='backpack__item'>
      <div class='backpack__itemName'>item_name</div>
      <div class='backpack__itemDescription'>item_hover</div>
    </div>
    <div class='backpack__item'>
      <div class='backpack__itemName'>item_name</div>
      <div class='backpack__itemDescription'>item_hover</div>
    </div>
    <div class='backpack__item'>
      <div class='backpack__itemName'>item_name</div>
      <div class='backpack__itemDescription'>item_hover</div>
    </div>
    <div class='backpack__item'>
      <div class='backpack__itemName'>item_name</div>
      <div class='backpack__itemDescription'>item_hover</div>
    </div>
    <div class='backpack__item'>
      <div class='backpack__itemName'>item_name</div>
      <div class='backpack__itemDescription'>item_hover</div>
    </div>
    <div class='backpack__item'>
      <div class='backpack__itemName'>item_name</div>
      <div class='backpack__itemDescription'>item_hover</div>
    </div>
    <div class='backpack__item'>
      <div class='backpack__itemName'>item_name</div>
      <div class='backpack__itemDescription'>item_hover</div>
    </div>
    <div class='backpack__item'>
      <div class='backpack__itemName'>item_name</div>
      <div class='backpack__itemDescription'>item_hover</div>
    </div>
    <div class='backpack__item'>
      <div class='backpack__itemName'>item_name</div>
      <div class='backpack__itemDescription'>item_hover</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Минуса два: описания должны быть довольно краткими и должно быть фиксированное количество блоков в строке.